# Slack notifications not working on Windows 8

Tags: notifications, windows-8, slack, system-sounds

I am using Windows 8. For some reason I haven't been receiving the slack notifications on my desktop. When I searched online for help, I got suggestions to turn off the focus assist, but it was of no help to me, as I didn't find anything like focus assist on my Windows 8 desktop. [Slack notifications settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPdtO.png)

I tried to enable notification sounds from the notifications and action center, but there was no option to enable the notifications for slack, all it was showing was windows apps only.

[Windows notifications settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNwlO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to turn off the focus assist, then you will get a slack notification. The below steps are for windows 10 but it may work for you too:

1. Go to the Start menu.
2. Click Settings > System.
3. From the right sidebar, select Focus Assist.
4. Select Off.